# WCF, Clientcredentials, multiple hop, kerberos and windows authentication - how to get working

Tags: wcf, authentication, kerberos, credentials

I have a web app running on Server A that calls a WCF service (K2 Workflow) on Server B that requires impersonation/delegation to run as the calling user.  If I run the web app from Server A, the app works great.  If I run the app from my local PC in debug, it also works great.  If I hit the app from a browser on my PC to Server A, I get the following error:

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Ntlm,Negotiate'. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout).

I use the following code to run the service:

```
SvcWorklist.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
SvcWorklist.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

I feel like I've done everything, here is a list of what I've tried:

1. Setup a SPN (including port) with by Server A App pool domain user to Server B
   (NETBIOS and FQDN)

   1. Set the same domain user as the app pool user on Server A and B
   2. Ensure the app pool user is allowed to delegate in Active directory
   3. Ensure both servers are allowed to delegate in AD
   4. Set authentication to windows and impersonate=true in web.config on Server A
   5. Ensured Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name has my user ID
   6. Ensured IIS is set for windows and impersonation
   7. Tried restricting the IIS configuration on server A and B to only Ntlm and/or Negotiate

Any help or ideas are truly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a similar issue as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928350/how-can-i-fix-the-kerberos-double-hop-issue

Comment: Yep, I read that.  Add (8) set useapppoolcreditials=true and (9) I don't have a load balancer.

Comment: Not that it helps but I'm facing the same issue so I'm monitoring this question to see if an answer pops-up...

Comment: Well, if you figure it out, tell me please!!!  I will do the same I promise.

Comment: I guess no one had any other ideas huh?  Don't blame you :)

Answer (score 0):

For the dude who had the same issue - I figured it out.  I had the SPN set on the target service, not the service it's hosting.  I also needed to set sharepoint to use negotiate versus ntlm.