# Login failed for user "DOMAIN\USER" when connecting to DB in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows

I have an asp.net application running in IIS using the account which has access to my database.  With windows authentication, I am able to log into this account in sql server manager and other things.  In my connection string, I have Integrated Security=true, and the error message I get when loading a page using this connection string references the correct user.  (Not 'IIS APPPOOL\ect...' like all the other instances of this question I have found on SO).  Is there something else that can cause this issue?  I just dont understand why I am able to log in with the same windows account in other applications.

Comment: You could try using `Integrated Security=SSPI`. Or maybe show your web.config for some more clues.

Comment: Are they two separate servers (web and DB) on a domain? Could be the Kerberos double-hop problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928350/how-can-i-fix-the-kerberos-double-hop-issue